# Sending email in ASP (CDO message) hangs about 5 to 10 secs each time

Tags: email, cdo.message

I'm sending an email using this code:

```
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Sign-up"
myMail.From="support@abc.com"
myMail.To="support@abc.com"
myMail.HTMLBody = signup
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtp.1and1.com"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
```

and while this is executed, the page hangs.  It takes about 5 to 10 seconds before it moves on.  Apologies if this is trivial but do I need a separate queuing mechanism because I don't this on other websites.  How are they doing this?

Comment: I have the same problem, Haven´t you resolve it yet?

Answer (score 1):

Does the mail get sent? You say it takes a few seconds before it moves on - what do you mean?

I looked at some of my asp cdo code that I have kicking around and I think you have to instantiate a CDO.Configuration object. Perhaps have a function that sets the config values for you, something like:

```
Function GetConfig()
Dim oConfig
Set oConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
oConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    'etc...
     oConfig.Fields.Update
     Set GetConfig = oConfig
End Function
```

Comment: The email gets sent OK.  What I mean is that if I have a redirect happening after the message sending, that redirect occurs 5 secs after the user started sending the email.

Comment: 5 secs is a little slow, but I could see it taking that long for CDO to contact the mail server and send the mail. Maybe you could use javascript to show a message telling the user that their mail is being sent and then the redirected page will confirm that it got sent. Also try instantiating the Configuration object above. Might speed it up.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It did speed it up a little.